# How do I compile *.src.zip back to .jar?

Tags: java

I have found a piece of program written in java (executable jar). I need to update the code somehow but I was confused how to compile this *.src.zip (from Java Decompiler) back to executable .jar...

I googled for almost 2 days already so I decide to create an account here maybe someone can teach by detail on how to do it... I already have jdk-8u45 (windows x86)...

Answer (score 1):

you need to install Java Eclipse, create a workplace, import the archive *.src.zip generated from a Java Decompiler then Run/Compile it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have all source code , I think it is a basic skill to compile the source code into jar no matter the tools you used.

For example ,you can install JDK and use command line to compile the source. Or you can install eclipse or Intellij IDEA to simply import the code into it , and then build a jar file.

At last , I just google `java code into jar`, it gives me many results , and here is just one of them:[Lesson: Packaging Programs in JAR Files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/)